# I need to separate a Text into paragraphs to get a list of strings. The delimiters will be repeated with a given pattern

Tags: c#, regex, string

In this text there are lines with the word Feature, this will be followed by several lines until a " (quote) is found.

I am interested in getting the the part in the middle between those two delimiters.  As long as Feature is the only word in that line.

For example:

```
bla bla bla bla bla bla Feature
bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla

Feature

ble bla bla bla bla

"bla bla bla bla bla blabla bla 
bla bla bla bla bla" Feature bla bla bla bla 

Feature 

bla bla bla bla bla

"bla bla bla bla bla blabla bla 
bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
```

outcome for this will be:
 ble bla bla bla bla,bla bla bla bla bla

and this pattern will be repeated over and over, I need to extract the part between the words Feature and the following " and store the paragraphs into a list. 
Looking online I can only find a way to do it extracting a string, not a collection of them. I am only extracting this when the word Features is the only word in its line. 
Also the method split wont work as the word Feature needs to be on a line only and the quotes need to be the next one

Another example:

> ```
>     bla bla bla bla
>
>     Feature
>
>     ble ble ble
>
>
>     " blu blu blu feature "
>
>     bli bli bli
>
>     Feature
>     blip blop ble
>
>     blip blop blup
>
>     " blo blo blo
> ```

The output for this one will be :
ble ble ble,blip blop ble blip blop blup

Thank you for your help

Comment: give an example of the desired output.

Comment: Can you give a better example with the expected results?  I'm not really clear on how that text is suppose to be split just based on your description.

Comment: cant control much regex, the output in this case will be

Comment: bla bla bla bla bla exactly the line after Feature

Comment: With example above, what is exactly the result you want it to be ?

Comment: another example will be

Comment: @yomismito "bla bla bla bla bla" is repeated multiple times in your example which is why it's not really a good example.  I think I know what you want though.  You want the two lines after the lines with just Feature and before the lines that start with a double quote?  And pleas edit the question, don't put examples in the comments.

Comment: Also is this text one big `string` or are you dealing with a collection of lines?

Comment: sorry I was in a meeting let me write a better example inside the question, as the comment doesnt allow me new lines

Comment: just wrote a different/better example

Comment: Yes the text is a big string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this do what you want? It will capture the paragraphs

```
Paragraph [0] - bla bla bla bla bla
Paragraph [1] - bla bla bla bla bla
```

If you need to capture a different bit the Regex can be adjusted.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using CommandLine;
using CommandLine.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {

    static int Main(string[] args)
    {
        string input = @"bla bla bla bla bla bla Feature
bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla

Feature

bla bla bla bla bla

""bla bla bla bla bla blabla bla 
bla bla bla bla bla"" Feature bla bla bla bla 

Feature 

bla bla bla bla bla

""bla bla bla bla bla blabla bla 
bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla ";

        //Matches:
        //  Any line starting with Feature (with optional whitespace)                   ^\s*Feature
        //  followed by newline (with optional whitespace)                              \s*\r\n
        //  then capturing anything that isn't a quote "                                ([^""]*)
        //  then ending with a quote                                                    \""
        Regex r = new Regex(@"^\s*Feature\s*\r\n([^""]*)\""",RegexOptions.Singleline | RegexOptions.Multiline);

        List<string> paragraphs = new List<string>();

        foreach (Match match in r.Matches(input))
            paragraphs.Add(match.Groups[1].Value.Trim());

        for (int i = 0; i < paragraphs.Count; i++)
            Console.WriteLine("Paragraph [{0}] - {1}", i, paragraphs[i]);

        Console.Read();
        return 0;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: it doesnt work your option, I have added a new example will your code work with this one too. Thank you for your help anyways!

Comment: Hey, can you explain how it doesn't work? does it match nothing or too much? Depending on your environment you might want \n instead of \r\n?

Comment: will your solution work with the second example I wrote?

Comment: I think so, I pasted in your second example this is the output (it captures up to the "):   
    Paragraph [0] - ble ble ble
    Paragraph [1] - blip blop ble

    blip blop blup

Answer (score 1):

Code below should give desired results.  I put data into a List>.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;


namespace ConsoleApplication86
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.txt";

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Boolean foundFeature = false;

            List<List<string>> data = new List<List<string>>();
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(FILENAME);
            string line = "";

            List<string> newFeature = null;
            while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                line = line.Trim();
                if (line.Length > 0)
                {
                    //ignore everything before 1st feature
                    if (foundFeature == false)
                    {
                        if (line.StartsWith("Feature"))
                        {
                            foundFeature = true;
                            newFeature = new List<string>();
                            data.Add(newFeature);
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (line.StartsWith("Feature"))
                        {
                            foundFeature = true;
                            newFeature = new List<string>();
                            data.Add(newFeature);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if(line.StartsWith("\""))
                            {
                                foundFeature = false;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                newFeature.Add(line);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            reader.Close();


         }

    }



}
```

Comment: I think the OP wants to stop at the first line that starts with a double quote after the Feature line.  Also consider using `File.ReadLines()` instead of creating a stream reader.  Also the Feature line should just be the word "Feature", not a line that just starts with "Feature".

Comment: I changed code to stop at double quotes.  I don't like reading all the lines which just increases memory usage.